# Why is my React app not showing up on Google and only accessible with "www"

Tags: reactjs, http, url, heroku

I have a React app hosted on Heroku with a domain I bought on GoDaddy (let's call it www.mydomain.org). I noticed today that I am not ranking anywhere in the first 10 pages for my (highly unusual) company name despite the site being live for a month, and if I search for mydomain.org it says this domain is parked for free by GoDaddy.

In fact, if I just enter "mydomain.org" into my URL bar it brings me to a GoDaddy page that says the same thing (parked for free). If I enter "www.mydomain.org" it successfully brings me to my web app.

How do I:
1. Get Google to crawl my app so searching for "mydomain" actually brings up my site? (this is not an SEO question -- I'm not asking how to rank for terms like web development, but for a made-up word that is pretty unique to my site)
2. Make sure that "mydomain.org" brings me to the right site and not a GoDaddy placeholder page? My impression was that the modern web did not require "www" to find the right domain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup you sitemap.xml and robot.txt, and let google know by adding a link to it via your Google Search Console.